# When does a map induce a structure in a concrete category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, set-theory, morphism

Let $C$ be a concrete category, let $A$ be a set, let $B$ be an object in $C$, and let $f$ be a function from $A$ to the underlying set of $B$.  Then does there always exist an object in $C$ whose underlying set is $A$ such that $f$ is a morphism in $C$?  And if $f$ is a bijection, then does there always exist an object in $C$ whose underlying set is $A$ such that $f$ is an isomorphism in $C$?

I assume the answer to these questions is no, but is there a name for concrete categories for which the answer to one or both questions is yes?  What if we switched the order of $A$ and $B$, so that the set which is being turned into an object is the codomain of the function rather than the domain?

I ask because inducing a structure on a set via a map is a very common construction in mathematics, and I’m wondering whether it’s category-theoretic in origin.

Comment: A related idea is [topological concrete categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category) where a family of functions induce a structure on their source or target.

Answer (score 4):

You're basically asking about **lifting properties** of the concretising functor $U: C \rightarrow \underline{Set}$. This should give you an idea what to search for if you want to look up more references on this. Note that we can also study these properties when the target category of the functor is something other than $\underline{Set}$.

Functors where we can lift any morphism are very rare. Indeed, you generally wouldn't expect forgetful functors of a concrete category to have this property, simply because the idea of a concrete category is that most functions in $\underline{Set}$ aren't morphisms of the structures than make up the concrete category.

The case where we can only lift bijections (only lift isomorphisms, for a general target category) are well known and studied, with the functors in question being called **isofibrations**. Your intuition that there are many such cases comes from, among other things, the fact that the forgetful functor from the category of algebras of a monad is always an isofibration.

Comment: There do exist functors that permit lifts along any morphism. The definition of lift is a little bit involved, though. These are called Grothendieck fibrations.

Comment: So is there a name for concrete categories whose forgetful functors are isofibrations?  And can you give me some (common in mathematics) examples of categories which are the category of algebras of some monad?  And more generally examples of concrete categories whose forgetful functors are isofibrations?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Almost any category from abstract algebra you care to name is the category of algebras for a monad: groups, rings, abelian groups, etc. Fields are not, but the forgetful functor is nevertheless an isofibration. Topological spaces are certainly not monadic, but the forgetful functor in this case is indeed an isofibration, and even a Grothendieck fibration, a property in general of "topological concrete categories", which are in a sense the other main class of concrete categories, alongside algebraic ones.

Comment: @KevinArlin So is it just a coincidence that the forgetful functors for fields and for topological spaces are isofibrations?  Or is there some more general class of concrete categories whose forgetful functors are isofibrations?  And are there any examples of concrete categories commonly encountered in mathematics whose forgetful functors are not isofibrations?

Comment: @KevinArlin Also do you have a reference where I can read more about the three results you discussed, i.e. forgetful functors being an isofibration for the category of algebras for a monad, the category of fields, and the category of topological spaces / all topological concrete categories?  Any category theory books that cover this sort of thing?  Ncatlab doesn’t seem to discuss it.

Answer (score 1):

No. Just consider the category $1$ with one object and one morphism (the identity), and map that into Set in pretty much any way.

Comment: So is there a name for concrete categories which do satisfy the property I describe?