# Is the forgetful functor of the category of models of a theory an isofibration?

Tags: logic, category-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory, functors

Let $T$ be a first-order theory, and let $C$ be the category of models of $T$, viewed as a concrete category.  Then my question is, is the forgetful functor of $C$ an isofibration?

The reason I ask is, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3797092/71829) says that the forgetful functor of the category of algebras over a given monad is an isofibration.  But the category of fields is not a category of algebras over a monad, yet its forgetful functor is still an isofibration.  So I’d like to find out if that’s just a coincidence or something true of all categories of models of a theory.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, of course. If I understand the definition of isofibration correctly, this unpacks to the standard "transfer of structure". Given a model $M$ and a bijection $f$ from the underlying set of $M$ to another set $X$, we can equip $X$ with a structure $N$ in the obvious way, which makes $f$ into an isomorphism from $M$ to $N$.

This has nothing to do with $M$ being a model of a first-order theory. For any language $L$, the category $\mathsf{Str}_L$ of $L$-structures is a concrete category such that the forgetful functor to Set is an isofibration. Now if you take any subcategory of $\mathsf{Str}_L$ which contains all the isomorphisms in $\mathsf{Str}_L$, the restriction of the forgetful functor to this subcategory will still be an isofibration. So the same result holds for any subcategory of $\mathsf{Str}_L$ which contains all the $L$-isomorphisms. In particular, the category of models of any theory in any reasonable logic (which talks about $L$-structures).

Comment: Can you spell out how to endow $X$ with a structure that makes $f$ into an isomorphism?

Comment: I recommend you try to solve this exercise yourself. It really is obvious, and I don't use that word carelessly! @KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I added a bit to my answer.